# jquery cascadind data is not binding it value

Tags: jquery

Here im implementing Cascading DropdownList Here Country value & its name is binding when i change country its value is comming but value is not binding at url.Im Getting error as `:44509/Api/Country/GetState/` Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
 DDLCOUNTRY.change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "-1") {
                DDLSTATE.empty();
                DDLSTATE.append('<option/>', { value: -1, text: 'Select Country' })

            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:44509/Api/Country/GetState/',
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: $(this).val() ,
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        alert('success...');
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: A `404` error means exactly what the error message is telling you.  That URL wasn't found on that server.  Check your server-side code.

Comment: Yes @David the url format is http://localhost:44509/Api/Country/GetState/1 Here i need to bind Country Id value to my url

Comment: Look, the error message is clear.  That URL doesn't exist on that server.  You can't bind anything to data that *doesn't exist*.  Check your *server-side* code.  If you don't *have* any server-side code, then that would be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your intention is to send the value then you can pass the parameter in the url, you can just do like this

```
$.ajax({url:'http://localhost:44509/Api/Country/GetState/id=' + $(this).val(),
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('success...');
                        }
                    });
```

and make sure that your "GetState" method is of type POST and is accepting parameter with name 'id'.